# C++ implementation of Monte Carlo Tree Search with Python wrapper

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, python-3.x, search

## Important

### Prebuilt Python Extensions built for Python 3.6

### Includes Python f-strings (3.6+)

#### Complementary GitHub link

https://github.com/thejhonnyguy/CPyMCTS

#### Notable: Previous attempt with stock Python

[Stock Monte Carlo Tree Search implementation to a simple connect 5 game in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/182582/115041) (Includes bugs)

C++ is the star of the show today with a custom MCTS implementation for the 5 in a row game. To build the `pyd` I used `boost.python` with Python 3.6 amd64 and x86 versions. (3.6.4 amd64, 3.6.5 x86)

## C++

### main.cpp

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include <string>
#include "boost/python.hpp"
#include "boost/python/def.hpp"
#include "boost/python/module.hpp"

#include "board.h"
#include "search.h"


BOOST_PYTHON_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(search_overloads, search, 2, 3);


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cpymcts)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<Board>("Board", init<>())
        .def(init<int>())
        .def("reset", &Board::reset)
        .def("play", &Board::playMove)
        .def("undo", &Board::undoMove)
        .def("get", &Board::getBoardPos)
        .def("check_win", &Board::checkWin)
        .add_property("string", &Board::showString)
        .add_property("size", &Board::getSize)
        .add_property("move_count", &Board::getMoves)
        ;
    def("search", search, search_overloads());
}
```

Below: `Node` class contained within `node.h` and `node.cpp`

### node.h

```
#pragma once
#include "board.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

// Node class

class Node
{
public:
    Node *parentNode;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;
    unsigned long visits;
    long long score;
    unsigned long visit_offset;
    int team_multiplier;
    int move_to[2];
    bool terminal;
    int termscore;

    // Constructors
    // Default. Will assume top node
    Node();
    // Norm
    Node(Node *parent, unsigned long offset, int mt_r, int mt_c, int term = 0);

    //Methods
    void Backtrack();
    void CreateChild(unsigned long offset, int mt_r, int mt_c, int term = 0);
    void BackPropagateScore(int s);
    bool IsLeaf();
    double ucb1();
    double ucb1(double exploration);
    Node* SelectBest(Board * board);
};
```

### node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"
#include "board.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


// Node implementations

Node::Node()
{
    // Default constuctor
    // Node * parentNode will be left undefined
    // It is the duty of the programmer to not do anything foolish
    parentNode = nullptr;
    visits = 0, score = 0, visit_offset = 0, team_multiplier = 1;
}

Node::Node(Node *parent, unsigned long offset, int mt_r, int mt_c, int term)
{
    // Constructor used when the node is not the top node.
    // int term default value 0
    parentNode = parent;
    move_to[0] = mt_r; move_to[1] = mt_c;
    visits = 0, score = 0, visit_offset = offset, team_multiplier = -parent->team_multiplier;
    if (term) terminal = true;
    termscore = term;
}

void Node::Backtrack()
{
    std::cout << "yeet" << std::endl;
    if (parentNode == nullptr) return;
    parentNode->Backtrack();
}

void Node::CreateChild(unsigned long offset, int mt_r, int mt_c, int term)
{
    // Creates a child and appends it to Node<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children
    // Nodes created here use the second constructor,
    // and `this` is the parent of its children, hence the `this` argument
    children.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(this, offset, mt_r, mt_c, term));
}

void Node::BackPropagateScore(int s)
{
    ++visits;
    score += s;
    if (parentNode == nullptr) return;
    parentNode->BackPropagateScore(s);
}

bool Node::IsLeaf()
{
    return !children.size();
}

double Node::ucb1()
{
    return ucb1(sqrt(2));
}

double Node::ucb1(double exploration)
{
    if (!visits) return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    double average = (double)score / visits;
    return team_multiplier * average + exploration * sqrt(log(parentNode->visits) / visits);
}

Node* Node::SelectBest(Board * board)
{
    if (parentNode != nullptr) board->playMove(move_to[0], move_to[1]);
    // This will only have effect on the top node.
    if (IsLeaf()) return this;
    double max_value = -1.0;
    int max_index = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
    {
        double tmp = children[i]->ucb1();
        if (tmp > max_value)
        {
            max_value = tmp;
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    return children[max_index]->SelectBest(board);
}
```

Below: `Board` class contained within `board.h` and `board.cpp`

### board.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <array>


// Class declaration and class method declarations go in the .h file here

class Board
{
private:
    short board[23][23];
    int lastPlaced[2];
    int size;
    int moves;
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> playedPieces;

public:

    Board(); // Default initialization to 19x19 board
    Board(int); // Initialization to NxN board

    std::string showString();
    void print();
    void reset();
    void playMove(int, int);
    void undoMove();
    void replayMoves();
    void manOverridePlayedPieces(std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> ov);
    int checkWin();
    int getMoves();
    int getSize();
    int getBoardPos(int r, int c);

    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> getObvMoves();
};
```

### board.cpp

```
#include "board.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>


// Board class implementation goes here (the literal functions)

Board::Board()
{
    size = 19;
    reset();
}

Board::Board(const int s)
{
    size = (s < 19) ? s : 19;
    reset();
}

std::string Board::showString()
{
    std::string str;
    for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; ++c)
        {
            str += std::to_string(board[r][c]);
            if (board[r][c] != -1) str += " ";
        }
        str += "\n";
    }
    return str;
}

void Board::print()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; ++c)
        {
            std::cout << board[r][c] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Board::reset()
{
    // Reset values
    moves = 0;

    // Reset board
    for (int r = 0; r < 23; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 23; ++c)
        {
            board[r][c] = 0;
        }
    }

    playedPieces.clear();
}


void Board::playMove(int r, int c)
{
    if (!board[r][c])
    {
        board[r][c] = (moves % 2) * 2 - 1;
    }
    else return;
    ++moves;

    lastPlaced[0] = r;
    lastPlaced[1] = c;
    std::array<int, 2> lp{ { r,c } };
    playedPieces.push_back(lp);
}

void Board::undoMove()
{
    board[lastPlaced[0]][lastPlaced[1]] = 0;
    --moves;
    playedPieces.pop_back();
    if (playedPieces.size())
    {
        lastPlaced[0] = playedPieces[playedPieces.size() - 1][0];
        lastPlaced[1] = playedPieces[playedPieces.size() - 1][1];
    }
}

void Board::replayMoves()
{
    std::cout << "Replaying moves:" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < playedPieces.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << playedPieces[i][0] << ", " << playedPieces[i][1] << std::endl;
    }
}

void Board::manOverridePlayedPieces(std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> ov)
{
    playedPieces = ov;
    moves = playedPieces.size();
}


int Board::checkWin()
{
    if (!moves) return 0;
    // Fast version: Check only the surroundings of the last placed piece
    int locR{ lastPlaced[0] };
    int locC{ lastPlaced[1] };

    // Check horizontal of the area. Verified to work.
    int startC{ (locC - 4 < 0) ? 0 : locC - 4 };
    int endC{ (size - locC >= 4) ? locC : size - 4 }; // Maths checks out
    for (int sC = startC; sC <= endC; ++sC)
    {
        int sum{ 0 };
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
        {
            sum += board[locR][sC + a];
        }
        if (sum == -5)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (sum == 5)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Check vertical of the area. Seems to work as well...
    int startR{ (locR - 4 < 0) ? 0 : locR - 4 };
    int endR{ (size - locR >= 4) ? locR : size - 4 };
    for (int sR = startR; sR <= endR; ++sR)
    {
        int sum{ 0 };
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
        {
            sum += board[sR + a][locC];
        }
        if (sum == -5)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (sum == 5)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Check the \ diagonal (top left to bottom right)
    // startR and startC will be used from above code for streamlining
    // delta-Row / delta-Col to be used in future
    int dRow = locR - startR;
    int dCol = locC - startC;
    int offset{ (dRow < dCol) ? dRow : dCol };
    // Too lazy for now to program more to truncate the search if it goes out of the zone
    // trust me I'm a programmer and it won't go out of index
    for (int sD = -offset; sD <= 0; ++sD)
    {
        int sum{ 0 };
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
        {
            sum += board[locR + sD + a][locC + sD + a];
            //std::cout << "Access: " << locR + sD + a << " " << locC + sD + a << std::endl;
        }
        if (sum == -5)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (sum == 5)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Check the / diagonal (bottom left to top right) - holy shit I hope this works
    // Calculate the offset to the left of which we start looking
    // Reuse `dRow` from last time
    offset = dCol; // I put a buffer so it won't go out of range
                   // Scenario: Top left of board. Program will go too far up. Going too far up is the only concern.
    int truncate{ (dRow < 4) ? dRow - 4 : 0 };
    for (int sD = -offset; sD <= truncate; ++sD)
    {
        int sum{ 0 };
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
        {
            sum += board[locR - sD - a][locC + sD + a];
            //std::cout << "Access: " << (locR + sD + a) << " " << (locC + sD + 4 - a) << std::endl;
            //std::cout << board[locR + sD + a][locC + sD + 4 - a] << " log" << std::endl;
        }
        if (sum == -5)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (sum == 5)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Draw
    return 0;
}

int Board::getMoves()
{
    return moves;
}

int Board::getSize()
{
    return size;
}

int Board::getBoardPos(int r, int c)
{
    return board[r][c];
}

std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> Board::getObvMoves() //TODO
{
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> adjCells;

    for (const std::array<int, 2>& piece : playedPieces)
    {
        int cpR = piece[0];
        int cpC = piece[1];

        std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> direcs;
        // Above
        direcs.push_back({ cpR - 1, cpC - 1 });
        direcs.push_back({ cpR - 1, cpC });
        direcs.push_back({ cpR - 1, cpC + 1 });
        // Beside
        direcs.push_back({ cpR, cpC - 1 });
        direcs.push_back({ cpR, cpC + 1 });
        // Below
        direcs.push_back({ cpR + 1, cpC - 1 });
        direcs.push_back({ cpR + 1, cpC });
        direcs.push_back({ cpR + 1, cpC + 1 });
        for (const std::array<int, 2>& direc : direcs)
        {
            if (std::find(adjCells.begin(), adjCells.end(), direc) != adjCells.end()) continue;
            if (direc[0] < 0 || direc[0] >= size || direc[1] < 0 || direc[1] >= size) continue;
            if (board[direc[0]][direc[1]]) continue;
            adjCells.push_back(direc);
        }
    }

    return adjCells;
}
```

Below: The MCTS algorithm used contained within `search.h` and `search.cpp`

### search.h

```
#pragma once
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include "boost/python/tuple.hpp"

#include "board.h"
#include "node.h"


boost::python::tuple search(Board inBoard, int team, unsigned long iterations = 10000);
void viewStats(Node* n, int t);
int simulation(Board board);
int simulation(Board board, bool rebuild);
```

### search.cpp

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include "boost/python/tuple.hpp"

#include "search.h"
#include "node.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


boost::python::tuple search(Board inBoard, int team, unsigned long iterations)
{
    std::cout << "Iterations being run: " << iterations << std::endl;
    if (!inBoard.getMoves())
    {
        std::cout << "Defaulting to middle of board for first move." << std::endl;
        return boost::python::make_tuple(inBoard.getSize() / 2, inBoard.getSize() / 2);
    }

    Node topNode;
    topNode.team_multiplier = -team;

    int info_every(std::max(unsigned long(2000), iterations / 5));

    /////////////////////////////// M C T S //////////////////////////////////
    for (unsigned long iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; ++iteration)
    {
        if (0 == iteration % info_every)
        {
            std::cout << "Progress %: " << iteration * 100 / iterations << std::endl;
            viewStats(&topNode, team);
        }
        Board tmp_board{ inBoard };
        Node* bestLeaf = topNode.SelectBest(&tmp_board);
        if (bestLeaf->terminal)
        {
            bestLeaf->BackPropagateScore(bestLeaf->termscore);
            continue;
        }
        if (!bestLeaf->visits)
        {
            int score = simulation(tmp_board, false);
            bestLeaf->BackPropagateScore(score);
            continue;
        }
        // Expand
        std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> obvMoves = tmp_board.getObvMoves();
        if (obvMoves.size() == 0)
        {
            bestLeaf->terminal = true;
            bestLeaf->termscore = 0; // tie
        }
        for (const std::array<int, 2>&move : obvMoves)
        {
            tmp_board.playMove(move[0], move[1]);
            int termscore = tmp_board.checkWin();
            if (termscore) bestLeaf->CreateChild(topNode.visits, move[0], move[1], termscore);
            bestLeaf->CreateChild(topNode.visits, move[0], move[1]);
            // Undo the move
            tmp_board.undoMove();
        }
    }

    // Suggest move

    int bestmove[2];
    unsigned long maxvisits = 0;
    for (const std::unique_ptr<Node>& move : topNode.children)
    {
        if (move->visits > maxvisits)
        {
            maxvisits = move->visits;
            bestmove[0] = move->move_to[0];
            bestmove[1] = move->move_to[1];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Suggest: " << bestmove[0] << "," << bestmove[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Win %:   " << team * topNode.score * 100 / topNode.visits << std::endl;

    return boost::python::make_tuple(bestmove[0], bestmove[1]);
}


void viewStats(Node * n, int t)
{
    if (n->children.size() == 0) return;
    int bestmove[2];
    unsigned long maxvisits = 0;
    for (const std::unique_ptr<Node>& move : n->children)
    {
        if (move->visits > maxvisits)
        {
            maxvisits = move->visits;
            bestmove[0] = move->move_to[0];
            bestmove[1] = move->move_to[1];
        }
    }
    if (maxvisits == 0 || n->visits == 0) return;
    std::cout << "Think: " << bestmove[0] << "," << bestmove[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Win %: " << t * n->score * 100 / n->visits << "\n" << std::endl;
}


int simulation(Board board)
{
    return simulation(board, true);
}

int simulation(Board board, bool rebuild)
{
    if (rebuild)
    {
        /* Rebuild the board states to make sure it works properly
           Will not guarantee proper working order initially, but
               for the purpose of this function, it will suffice
        */
        std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> tmp;
        for (int r = 0; r < board.getSize(); ++r)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < board.getSize(); ++c)
            {
                if (board.getBoardPos(r, c)) tmp.push_back(std::array<int, 2>{ r, c });
            }
        }
        board.manOverridePlayedPieces(tmp);
    }

    while (board.getMoves() < pow(board.getSize(), 2))
    {
        // Make a random move
        std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> choices = board.getObvMoves();
        std::array<int, 2> randMove = choices[rand() % choices.size()];
        board.playMove(randMove[0], randMove[1]);
        if (board.checkWin()) return board.checkWin();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Python

Below: the loader and module scripts

### loader.py

```
import sys


if sys.maxsize == 2147483647:  # 32 bit python install
    from x86.cpymcts import Board, search

else:  # 64 bit
    from x64.cpymcts import Board, search
```

### Reach.py (fancy naming)

````
"""
This script is designed to function as a higher level interface
to an end user & programmer. It also handles input checking and such
NO functionality is removed because of this
"""
from typing import Tuple
from loader import Board as Board_, search as search_


class Board:

    def __init__(self, size: int = 19) -> None:
        if size <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Bad value for size.")
        if size > 19:
            raise ValueError("Size may not be larger than 19.")
        self.board = Board_(size)

    # Read only properties and (magic) methods
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.board.string.replace('-1', 'X ').replace('1', 'O')

    @property
    def size(self) -> int:
        """Returns the size of the board. If 19x19 then will return 19"""
        return self.board.size

    @property
    def move_count(self) -> int:
        """Moves that have been played since game start minus undone moves"""
        return self.board.move_count

    def check_win(self) -> int:
        """Returns -1 for P1 win, 0 for no win, 1 for P2 win"""
        return self.board.check_win()

    # The remainder of the methods to interface with Board_
    def reset(self) -> None:
        """Resets to a new instance of `Board`"""
        self.board.reset()

    def search(self, team: int = None, iterations: int = 10000
            ) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        """
        An alias for search(Board, int, int). Please see Reach.search
        ```python
        >>> a = Board()
        >>> a.search()
        (9, 9)
        >>> b = Board()
        >>> search(b)
        (9, 9)
        ```
        """
        return search(self, team, iterations)

    def get(self, row: int, col: int) -> int:
        """
        Gets the piece (-1, 1 or 0) where -1 is a black stone (player 1)
            and 1 is a white stone, and 0 is empty of the position.
        ```python
        >>> a = Board()
        >>> a.play(9, 9)
        >>> a.get(9, 9)
        -1
        ```

        Args:  
        row: `int`
            The row of the piece starting from 0  

        col: `int`
            The column of the piece starting from 0  

        Returns:  
        piece: `int`
            The piece at the position (row, col) of the board.  

        Raises:  
        `IndexError`
            row or col are out of bounds.
        """
        if not 0 <= row < self.size or not 0 <= col < self.size:
            raise IndexError(f"Invalid coordinates (row, col): ({row}, {col}) "
                            f"exceeds dimentions of {self.size}x{self.size}.")
        return self.board.get(row, col)

    def play(self, row: int, col: int) -> None:
        """
        Places a piece at the location (row, col)  
        Args:  
        row `int`:
            The row of which to place the piece  
        col `int`:
            The column of which to place the piece  

        Raises:  
        `ValueError`
            row or col are out of bounds.
        """
        if not 0 <= row < self.size or not 0 <= col < self.size:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid coordinates (row, col): ({row}, {col}) "
                            f"exceeds dimentions of {self.size}x{self.size}.")
        self.board.play(row, col)

    def undo(self) -> None:
        """Undoes the last move. May be called multiple times."""
        self.board.undo()


def search(ref_board: Board, team: int = None, iterations: int = 10000
        ) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Args:  
    ref_board: `Board`
        The board to be examined.  
    team: `int`
        The number of the piece that will be played this turn. First player is \
-1  
    iterations: `int`
        The amount of MCTS iterations to run.  

    Returns:  
    bestmove: `Tuple[int, int]`
        A 2-tuple of the position to place the next piece for best perceived \
outcome  

    Raises:
    `ValueError`
        when there is an object type mismatch

    ```python
    >>> a = Board()
    >>> a.search()
    (9, 9)
    >>> b = Board()
    >>> search(b)
    (9, 9)
    ```
    """
    if team is not None:
        print('You have chosen to manually overwrite the `team` parameter. '
            'It is recommended to allow this to handle this automatically.')
    else:
        team = (ref_board.move_count % 2) * 2 - 1

    if not isinstance(team, int):
        raise ValueError(f"team should be of {int} and not "
                        f"{type(team)}")
    if not isinstance(iterations, int):
        raise ValueError(f"iterations should be of {int} and not "
                        f"{type(iterations)}.")

    if isinstance(ref_board, Board):
        return search_(ref_board.board, team, iterations)
    elif isinstance(ref_board, Board_):
        return search_(ref_board, team, iterations)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"ref_board should be of {Board} or {Board_} and not"
                        f" {type(ref_board)}.")
````

This is my first ever C++ work.
Not my first Python work, however, hence the overall higher quality. Now with...

✔ Python within 80 characters at all times
✔ Python functions well documented
✘ Lack of comments at some places
✘ This is your job to complain, not mine.

Give feedback on any of two languages.